# Angular JS Parent Scope Click Handler Not Destroyed

Tags: angularjs, scope

This is my html

```
<div controller="parent">
<button ng-click="doSomething()"><Click</button>
<div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Here is my js controller for a particular view:

```
function child($scope) {
   $scope.$parent.doSomething = function() {
      // do http request or seomthing else
   }
}
```

Now when Im on the child controller view, angular does http request when i click on the button on the parent scope but when I navigate to other views with different controllers (of course), angular still does http request when I click on the button on the parent scope.

I thought when the view changes, the controller and including its scope will be destroyed and thereby effectively removing references to that particular scope objects.

My work around is to listen for $scope.on('$destroy') and override the function to return empty or something else.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope.$parent.doSomething` is adding the `doSomething` property to that parent $scope object. So long as that parent scope doesn't get destroyed, your click handler will stick around.

Comment: ok thanks.. isn't there a way to do this? i mean maybe i can try to listen route change and then override the click handler maybe?

Comment: You could have the parent scope broadcast an event down the scope, then handle that event how you would like in each of the children that receive it.

Edit: that means the ng-click on the parent would do a $scope.$broadcast("SomeEventName") and each of the children that you want to receive and handle that click event can listen for it with $scope.$on("SomeEventName", function(event){ ... }

Comment: yeah but i do still have to unbind the listener on scope destroys, right?.

Comment: Nope, just handle it appropriately in each of your child controllers. If you don't care about that click event in certain views, then don't even bother listening for it on those controllers. Otherwise, you can set some kind of conditional check inside of the `$scope.$on` function to prevent inner code execution.

`$scope.$on("SomeEventName", function(event){
    if (someConditionalCheck){
        // do something if true, otherwise, do nothing
    }
});`